# Filtering Only Original Tweets in a tweepy.Stream

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I'm writing a Twitter bot using [Tweepy](https://www.tweepy.org/) to retweet the tweets that have specific keywords.

Using the method `is_not_a_reply`, I tried to retweet only the tweets that are not a reply to another tweet. It works correctly almost 99% of the time, but rarely are some replies still retweeted.

**I really don't know what's wrong with my code!!!**

```py
import os
import tweepy
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# take environment variables from .env.
load_dotenv()

# get environment variables for Twitter API
consumer_key = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_KEY")
consumer_secret = os.environ.get("CONSUMER_SECRET")
access_token = os.environ.get("ACCESS_TOKEN")
access_token_secret = os.environ.get("ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET")


def twitter_api_authenticate():
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    return tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


class MyStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def __init__(
        self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
    ):
        super().__init__(
            consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
        )
        self.twitterApi = twitter_api_authenticate()

    # when a new tweet is posted on Twitter with my filtered keywords
    def on_status(self, status):

        # If the found tweet is not a reply to another tweet
        if self.is_not_a_reply(status):

            # Retweet the found tweet (status)
            self.retweet(status)
            # Like the found tweet (status)
            self.like(status)

    def retweet(self, status):
        # Retweet the tweet
        self.twitterApi.retweet(status.id)

    def like(self, status):
        # Like the tweet
        self.twitterApi.create_favorite(status.id)

    def is_not_a_reply(self, status):
        if status.in_reply_to_status_id == None:
            return True
        else:
            return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    trackList = ["Keyword1", "Keyword2"]

    stream = MyStream(
        consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
    )
    stream.filter(track=trackList, languages=["fa"])
```

```
Tweepy version: 4.1.0
Python version: 3.8.10
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you sure those Tweets are replies and not just Tweets with mentions? Can you provide an example of one of these Tweets?

Comment: @Harmon758 Yes, I'm sure they are replies. Anyway, I found my mistake a moment ago, those tweets are not replies themselves but retweets of replies! Now I should check if the filtered tweet is a retweeted reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. The unwanted tweets are not replies themselves but retweets of a reply!

This was due to my poor understanding of the [tweet object in Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/data-dictionary/object-model/tweet). In the Twitter API the retweet of a reply is not considered a reply itself.

So I must first check whether the filtered tweet is a "retweet" or not and then check whether it is a "reply" or not.

According to the point [rv.kvetch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10237506/rv-kvetch) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69770896/5000746), I modified the `is_not_a_reply` method as follows:

```py
    def is_not_a_reply(self, status):
        if hasattr(status, "retweeted_status"):
            # Check the original tweet if it was a retweet
            originalStatus = self.twitterApi.get_status(id=status.retweeted_status.id)
            return not originalStatus.in_reply_to_status_id
        else:
            # Check the tweet itself
            return not status.in_reply_to_status_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but you can always try to simplify the logic in the `is_not_a_reply` method. For debugging, I'd also suggest logging the `status` object and the `in_reply_to_status_id` attribute for example.

```
def is_not_a_reply(self, status):
    return not status.in_reply_to_status_id
```

Note that in the original version, you were doing a `==` comparison with None, but if you use an IDE it'll suggest having it like `is` and `is not`, because that's the ideal way to do comparisons with None or a boolean. In this case I've just updated it to handle any "falsy" value like a 0 value or an empty list - again, it all depends on what the type of
`in_reply_to_status_id` is here.

Comment: That's a good point, but the problem was not in the code. It was because of my bad understanding of the Twitter API. In the Twitter API the retweet of a reply is not considered a reply itself. I have to check the original tweet of the retweet!